# How to create simple Boost.Build make file containing links to libs I use on Windows and Linux?

Tags: c++, boost, configuration, makefile, bjam

`main.cpp` which should be executable C++ app. It shall depend on

- Lib1 be a required to be compiled first (before main.cpp) project-lib (with lib1.h and lib1.cpp inside some separate folders)
- 'Lib2.lib' with its dependency given precompiled libs (like cross-platform OpenCV for example)

I need it to work for Windows and Linux and if possible Mac OS

found for windows: look [here - "Common tasks"](http://www.boost.org/doc/tools/build/doc/userman.pdf) page 26

```
exe hello : hello.cpp some_library.lib /some_project//library
          : <threading>multi
          ;
```

I hoped for better - more readable syntax form Boost creators... And BTW

What the hell on earth does

> On Windows, if an application uses
>   shared libraries, and both the
>   application and the libraries are
>   built using Boost.Build, it is not
>   possible to immediately run the
>   application, because the PATH 
>   environment variable should include
>   the path to the libraries. It means
>   you have to either add the paths
>   manually, or have the build place the
>   application and the libraries into the
>   same directory.

mean? I can not have a project with 2 nested project - one for .lib and one for app using that .lib?

With this I see how to connect 1 .lib but how to connect a folder with them? And how to connect includes? And when I'll go to Linux what shall be changed?

How should my bjam make/config file look like?

Comment: "simple Boost.Build make file" is an oxymoron. I wasted many hours with this. Not recommended.

Comment: yep... Boost.build is not what I hoped... but any way I use boost and other cross-platform (actually only cross-platform libs) a lot in my project that currently works under windows and which I need to build for mac os and lin...

Comment: Do you want to link to lib1.lib and lib2.dll that already exist, or do you want them to be built from sources as well? Also, on windows, you cannot link to lib2.dll easily -- you generally should link to import library for it, typically named lib2.lib. Could you clarify what you actually want.

Comment: So... for my purposes I need lib1 be a required to be compiled first (before main.cpp) project-lib (with lib1.h and lib1.cpp inside some separate folders) and lib2.lib with its dependency given precompiled libs (like OpenCV for example)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a framework which works on a cross-platform(Multiple operating system) scenario.

Simplest option would be to install cygwin and create a standard makefile for linux. Compile in a cygwin environment to generate the windows equivalent.

You will save substantial time in creating the makefile.

Another option is  mksnt.